# JSON Validator for Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, json

I'm looking for a plugin that can check the current opened file and instantly tell me whether it is valid JSON or not (eg whether there's a comma or a bracket missing) — is there any? I'm currently using JSONView on Chrome but it's a pain to always go check the file in the browser and back.

I'm often writing data in json by hand, hence why I feel this could save me a lot of time.

Comment: Not a plugin for Notepad++ but XML ValidatorBuddy is also a JSON editor and comes with a built-in JSON syntax checker and auto-completion. It is a standalone Windows tool.

Comment: You can use Codverter JSON Validator: https://codverter.com/src/jsonvalidator 
it`s highly secure and everything you do is interpreted on your local computer and never sent back to the server. the validation error messages are informative and accurate.
(Full Disclosure: I am one of the developers).

Answer (score 10):

You might be able to use a JSON formatter to accomplish the task (since it would likely complain or do something wrong -- say, like indent improperly -- if the JSON's invalid). See [Is there an extension to reindent JSON in Notepad++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1560464/355230). Similarly, there's a [JSONViewer Notepad++ plugin](http://nppjsonviewer.sourceforge.net/) the might help in the same way.

Another less-than-ideal alternative would be to just use one of the online [JSON validators](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&as_q=json+validator&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=off&tbs=&as_filetype=&as_rights=).

Comment: +1 for JSON Viewer- I use it all the time. can also format/reindent your JSON string. Only thing is you have to manually use the functionality- I don't think you can do it every time a .json file is opened

Comment: Thanks, I upvoted, but it's still not quite what I hoped for; JSMin ignores errors, and JSON Viewer while it does fail if the json is not properly formatted, I still get much more if I parse it using JSONView in Google Chrome since as opposed to JSON Viewer it tells exactly what is missing and where. Oh well. I suppose I can only hope someday somebody able to code npp plugins comes across this and implements a simple one-button solution to parse and validate json.

Comment: @Mahn: Thanks. _Necessity is the mother of invention_, so perhaps you should be that someone...

Comment: I'd love to, but I'm involved in a somewhat big project atm and time is ticking out :) maybe someday.

Comment: It's worth noting that the JSONView Chrome extension does a great job but crashes on significantly large files (can't get it to process a 90meg file... not sure what it's limit is though).

Comment: Online JSON validators are not an option if you have sensitive personal data stored in the JSON.

Comment: Yeah, most companies don't like you copy/pasta-ing config, etc json files up into the public interwebs.  If you use JSONView -> Format Json, it will throw an error and select the problematic area of the JSON document.  I'm sure it could be made to be fancier and provide more of an explanation, but it works well enough for my needs.

Answer (score 4):

There is plugin for NPP+ called JSLint. It is a plugin to validate JavaScript-code, but it works also just fine with JSON-files.

Comment: Does not seem to work for me. It says "JSLint can operate only on JavaScript, HTML or CSS files". Saving my .json file as .js file does not help.

Comment: Works just fine when saving the file as JavaScript file running Notepad++ 7.8.7 and JSLint 0.8.3.199. Remember to open the copy if you chose "Save a copy" from the file menu before running JSLint.

Comment: I had to save my json file with the .js extension first