# Is there a way to validate JSON in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

[JSON Validator for Notepad++?](https://superuser.com/questions/446482/json-validator-for-notepad) was closed, and none of the links there point to an actual **validator** for JSON data.

I don't need to reformat JSON, I want a visual cue that I've missed a comma or a bracket.

How do I make Notepad++ do this, even if only like it would in XML if I did not close a string?

Thanks!

Comment: mhhhmm ... so your question is asking for an actual plugin?

Comment: @aybiss,  You might try the stand-alone free JSONEdit, http://tomeko.net/software/JSONedit/ [This comment is acknowledged as off-topic because it belongs in software recommendations, so I'll delete it if desired.]

Comment: @bummi well i wouldn't want to be asking for a software recommendation, but if you know of one i'll accept it as the answer :-)

Comment: @DrMoishePippik that looks really nice but i spend half my days editing XML, JSON, INI and so many other files in Notepad++. VisualStudio itself validates JSON if you load it up, but it takes so long to load the application it's not workable. I really do need to keep using my "one-stop-shop" text editor where I've defined macros and so forth, I just want to be able to do one more thing with it.

Comment: With the [JSON Viewer plugin](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nppjsonviewer/), you'll get an error message if the JSON is malformed.

Comment: @Toto only if you close and reopen the viewer. And there's no keyboard shortcut to close it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Codverter JSON Validator](https://codverter.com/src/jsonvalidator), it`s online and highly secure, everything you do is interpreted on your local computer and never sent back to the server.
 the validation error messages are informative and accurate.

(Full Disclosure: I am one of the developers).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The "Format JSON" option of the JSON Viewer will give an error if the JSON is not correct and also will select the incorrect text.

If the JSON is correct it will reformat but you can use undo (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>) to get it back to the previous format.